# How to use form control name in label - angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular reactive forms and in my form for one field containing label to populate value and remaining all fields contain form control names. And I am trying to set data from service through subscribe. So here I am able to populate all form data through form control names except label. As label does not contain form control name so I am unable to set value to that.

This is my form:

```js
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
    
            
                <label>
                Roll number
                </label>
         
          
              <label>
                {{rollnum}}
              </label>
            
</div>
```

Usually now I am setting for other fields like this

```
  myForm.control.formcontrolname.setValue('value');
```

If it is same component then I can assign value to `rollnum` so that that value will populate, but from some other service how can i set value to the rollnum and is there any way to use formcontrolname for that label.

Comment: where is `formControlName` set in template file?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I don't know how to use formControlName to the label

Comment: `[columnNumbers]` what is this in `div` tag?

Comment: Is your problem that the {{rollnum}} is not getting displayed ?

Comment: @nXn Actually I'm struggling to set formcontrolname for this.. If i initialise directly in component  like rollnum = 'Xyz', this value will be displaying in ui but if I want to set value from other service how can we set that value?

Comment: you can import the service in the ts file, and assign it to a variable

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agddlg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts  checkout this link.. is it what do you want here?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Thanks for your time..yeah even i'm trying the same but here in my case initially component will load and data also will come to service after performing some operation, so my component is not getting value

Comment: edit stackblitz link and show your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing your comments, I understand that you need to show the content on {{rollnum}} only once the data is loaded from the service.

Please try this code below 
In your ts file, declare a variable call dataLoaded. This variable will be a boolean that can hold values true and false. Initialy we will set it to false.

```
dataLoaded : boolean = false;
```

Next we will call the service to load the data.

```
serviceToLoadData(){
   this.serviceCall.getdata().subscribe((data)=>{
    // here you would do the processing of the data and the data will be loaded to 
    //rollnum.
    //Once the data is loaded set the value of dataLoaded to true.
    this.dataLoaded = true;
   });
}
```

In you HTML file

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">


                <label class="bx--label" style ="margin-left: 4rem">
                Roll number
                </label>


              <label *ngIf="dataLoaded" class="bx--label" style ="margin-left: 1rem">
                {{rollnum}}
              </label>

</div>
```

Here in this case the label will be shown only if dataLoaded is true.

You can apply the same principle to the div. On the div you can apply ngIf.

Hope this solves the issue.